# How do I set a "gets" call with default input value?

Tags: ruby

If I have a `gets.chomp` statement, how do I set it such that the default input is a custom message?

```
favorite_ice_cream = gets.chomp(default_message)  #I know this isn't valid Ruby syntax

=> Chocolate
```

I want to have the ability to edit the input string "chocolate" in the terminal before I enter it as user input.

Comment: You are confusing browser behavior with the console. They are worlds apart in functionality.

Comment: Why would you want a "default value" for the gets statement? What behaviour should that have? It sounds like you should validate the input afterwards. Or, as @theTinMan says, you might be confusing something for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this.  You'll have to implement a thread to wait a fraction of a second to write to the STDIO (input) with your `gets` command in place and running.  Other then that you'll just have to print it to the screen and have the person retype it.

I recommend the gem [highline](https://github.com/JEG2/highline) for user input.  Instead of `gets` you can use `ask` and provide a default: `ask("Company? ") { |q| q.default = "none" }` which outputs `Company?  |none|`.  That lets you just hit the `ENTER` key for the default **none** to be used, or you can type (but not edit) a new entry.

With highline you won't have to use chomp.

But the answer to your question is to use threads to have an IO stream write to the input while `gets` is waiting for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I found `prompt.ask` from [`tty-prompt`](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-prompt) fulfilled my need better than highline because it displays an editable default value:

```sh
$ gem install tty-prompt

$ irb
```

```rb
irb(main):001:0> require "tty-prompt"
=> true

irb(main):002:0> prompt = TTY::Prompt.new
=> #<TTY::Prompt prefix="" quiet=false enabled_color=nil active_color=:green 
error_color=:red help_color=:bright_black input=#<IO:<ST...

irb(main):003:0> prompt.ask("What is your name?", default: ENV["USER"])
What is your name? xxx
=> "xxx"

irb(main):004:0> prompt.ask("What is your name?", value: "Mike")
What is your name? Michael
=> "Michael"
```